# Dereferencing Iterator to Custom Struct Field

Tags: c++, struct, iterator, dereference

I have a vector players which I would like to iterate over. The 'player' struct appears as follows:

`struct player {
    string name;
    int rating;
};`

I am using the iterator in a for loop to see if any of the 'players' have the name 'playerName' (a string).

`for (vector<player>::iterator itr = players.begin(); itr != players.end(); ++itr) {
    if (playerName.compare(*itr->name) == 0) return true;
}
return false;`

Unfortunately, I keep running into an error: 'error C2100: illegal indirection' (visual C++ 2008). I believe that I'm dereferencing the iterator incorrectly; is there a better way to do so?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`*itr->name` is equivalent to `(*itr)->name`.

In your code, the type of `(*itr)` is `player`, not `player*`, so the compiler is basically telling you that you're trying to dereference something that isn't a pointer.

The correct way of doing that would be `(*itr).name` or `itr->name`, both meaning "dereference itr then access name".

Answer (score 2):

I believe that I'm dereferencing the iterator incorrectly;

See corrected code:

```
if (playerName.compare(itr->name) == 0)
```

or

```
if (playerName.compare((*itr).name) == 0)
```